# Custom Form Builder in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to write a custom form builder in Rails to (among other things) automatically add a CSS class to each field I create.

I'd like to extend, for example, text_field to add in the class I need.  But the code below, which I would expect would just pass behavior to the standard FormBuilder, fails with an error of the wrong number of arguments.  "wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)"

```
class BootstrapFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    def text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
        super(object_name, method, options)
    end
end
```

If I look at the Rails source, I see the definition of text_field as:

```
def text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
```

Help please!  (Bonus points if you throw in the code to merge ":class => 'some_class'" into the options hash along the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rails source you are referring to shows that `text_field` has two parameters not three.  See [`FormBuilder`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1282) source from github.

So update your form builder class as:

```
class BootstrapFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    def text_field(method, options = {})
        super(method, options)
    end
end
```

Then the usage of this, including the `class` option you want to add:

```
<%= form_for :foo, builder: BootstrapFormBuilder do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :foo_field, class: 'bootstrap_text_field' %>
<% end %>
```

Any options you pass in to the default `FormBuilder` are also available to this child class, so use the `class` option as you would for default form builder.

Comment: Any chance you could point me to the source for f.select?  I'm not finding it in the FormBuilder link you gave above... Thanks!

Comment: @GregRogers, the `select` helper is in [`form_options_helper.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L640)